# How to pass value from onSesorChanged() at regular intervals

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) {

        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, event.values);

        azimuth = (int) ((Math.toDegrees(SensorManager.getOrientation(rotationMatrix, orientation)[0]) + 360) % 360);
        txt_azimuth.setText("Azimuth : " + Integer.toString(azimuth) + "° " + n);

        if (azimuth >= 337 && azimuth <= 360 || azimuth >= 0 && azimuth <= 22) {
            n = "N"; // 0 deg

        } else if (azimuth > 22 && azimuth < 68) {
            n = "NE"; //45 deg

        } else if (azimuth >= 68 && azimuth <= 112) {
            n = "E"; // 90deg

        } else if (azimuth > 112 && azimuth < 157) {
            n = "SE"; //135deg

        } else if (azimuth >= 157 && azimuth <= 203) {
            n = "S"; //180deg

        } else if (azimuth > 203 && azimuth < 248) {
            n = "SW"; //225deg

        } else if (azimuth >= 248 && azimuth <= 293) {
            n = "W"; //270deg

        } else if (azimuth > 293 && azimuth < 337) {
            n = "NW";//315deg

        }

            try {

                ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().publishEvent("function name", n, ParticleEventVisibility.PUBLIC, 60);


            } catch (ParticleCloudException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
           }

       }
  }
```

`onSensorChanged()` method is called many times (maybe thousand times) per second when phone is moving. I can see the value on n orientation on the app screen. That part is working. But what I want to do is to make method `publish.event()` to be called once per second to take the value of n at that moment and publish it to the cloud. So basically, the orientation should be published once per second. 
I cannot figure it out how to make it work at intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Store required data in a variable, Create a task to run the update function at fixed intervals with the timer function,

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```